# Powershell - odd line feed behaviour

Tags: powershell

I'n new to Powershell so apologies if this is an obvious question. I have the following function which delimits a string:

```
 [int[]]$rec02 = 3,2,1,4,3,3,5,5,6,1,19,45,2,3,50

 function delimitString([string]$text, [int[]]$arrDelims)
        {
                [string]$out;
                [int]$total=0;
                foreach($d in $arrDelims)
                {        
                    $out += $text.substring($total,$d)+",";
                    $total +=$d;
                }

                $out += $text.substring($total,$text.length-$total)+",";
                return $out;
        }
```

When this is called as follows:
    delimitString "gjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjlllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffllllllllll" $rec02

How can I suppress/why are there new line/carriage returns at the start/end of the output?

gjj,jj,j,jjjj,jjj,jjj,jjjjj,jjjjj,jjjjjj,j,jjjjlllllllllllllll,llllllllllllllll
lllllllllllllllllllllllllllll,ll,lll,llllllllllllllllllllllllllffffffffffffffff
ffffffff,ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffllllllllll,

I eventually write this to a file and therefore I am ending up with blank lines in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[string]$out` is not initialization. It jost outputs variable named 'out' as an addition to return. As there is not `$out` variable, before output it creates it with default value (empty string). When outputting this manner, it adds newline at the end of each outputting line.

So, `[string]$out` is actually (in your case) `New-Object -TypeName 'System.String' -ArgumentList @([System.String]::Empty)`, as you see it is Function that returns an object

The same problem is with New-Item function. It returns new item's object, so, when you use it in function, you should send output to null

```
    Function TestReturn {
    New-Item -Path $( [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + '.test' ) -ItemType 'File'
    New-Item -Path $( [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + '.test' ) -ItemType 'File'
    return "Hello, World"
}
TestReturn
```

returns

```
;    Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                             
;----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                             
;-a---        26.07.2014      9:08          0 tmpD9B4.tmp.test                                                                                                                                 
;-a---        26.07.2014      9:08          0 tmpDA03.tmp.test                                                                                                                                 
;Hello, World
```

To omit this, you should use `New-Item ... | Out-Null` or put value into a variable `$temp = New-Item ...` 
So the correct form is (scroll right!)

```
        Function TestReturn {
    New-Item -Path $( [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + '.test' ) -ItemType 'File' | Out-Null
    New-Item -Path $( [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + '.test' ) -ItemType 'File' | Out-Null
    return "Hello, World"
}
TestReturn
```

Because of this you should use `$out=''` or (it you fan typization) `$out=[String]''` instead of `[string]$out` . Those to lines do VERY different things. You line tries to create and output variable. Line `$out=''` just initializes it.

To write to a file you should use `$somevar | Out-File` or `OutFile -InputObject` form

```
[int[]]$rec02 = @(3,2,1,4,3,3,5,5,6,1,19,45,2,3,50)

 function delimitString([string]$text, [int[]]$arrDelims)
        {
                $out='';
                $total=0;
                foreach($d in $arrDelims)
                {        
                    $out += $text.substring($total,$d)+",";
                    $total +=$d;
                }

                $out += $text.substring($total,$text.length-$total)+",";
                return $out 
        }
$tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$somevar = delimitString "gjjj...." $rec02 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline "BEGIN"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline $somevar
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "END"

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Out Length: $($somevar.Length)"
$tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "TempFile: $($tempFile)"
Out-File -FilePath $tempFile -Encoding 'Ascii' -InputObject $somevar
$somevar = Get-Content -Path $tempFile -Encoding 'Ascii'
```

NB: Out-File with Encoding 'UTF-8' adds BOM record at the beginning. To avoid this use `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($path,$data,[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I well understood the question, but it seems you are trying to initialize variable this way `[string]$out;`. In fact you are only printing the `$out` variable (which you never used before) as a string, so you don't get the result you expect by using this piece of code `$out +=` to add something to a string.

Just try change this `[string]$out;` to this `$out = "";` and you should be able to run your code correctly (now `$out` is a `String`).

Comment: I have amended the usage example slightly. In essence I call the function with a string and split it in intervals defined in the functions input array. I use the out variable to build up the delimited string - this is being assigned to and the output is correct however the start/end of the output has unexpected carriage return/line feed chars.

Comment: What you get if you try to save the returned value into a variable, let call it `$a`, and then you call `$a.GetType().fullname`? Do you Get `System.Object[]` or `System.String`?

Comment: very strange, if I try to execute it I get a `System.Object[]`

Comment: Is that not the base type?

Comment: `("a").GetType().FullName` -> System.String
`@("a").GetType().FullName` -> System.Object[]
I get a System.Object[] as output variable from your function, if you get a System.String maybe we are looking at a different piece of code ;)

Comment: The suggestion by @LorenzoC (change [string]$out; to $out="") worked for me. Original code is writing an empty line to the output stream which PowerShell combines with the intended output (return $out) into an array.